# Creating a list of strings from a portion of textbox in PowerPoint using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint presentation with many slides, all of which only have one text box.
I am trying to shuffle slides and ensure that the first line from the textbox is unique on the five slides after the header slide.

My idea is to create a list containing the first line of a textbox of a PowerPoint slide from slide number 2 to slide number 6.
To make sure each value in this list is unique is to iterate over this list and upon discovery of a duplicate value to send the slide to the end of the presentation.

I am lost after implementing the initial shuffle.

```vb
Sub ShuffleSlides()
numStart = 1
numStop = 5
FirstSlide = 2
LastSlide = 21

Randomize
For j = numStart To numStop
    For i = FirstSlide To LastSlide
        RSN = Int((LastSlide - FirstSlide + 1) * Rnd + FirstSlide)
        ActivePresentation.Slides(i).MoveTo (RSN)
    Next i
Next j

End Sub
```

How can I retrieve the first line from each textbox to make this list?

Answer (score 0):

Please try.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ShuffleSlides()
    Dim Sld As Slide, Shp As Shape
    Dim oDic, aTxt, i As Long, RSN
    Const NumStop = 5
    Const FirstSlide = 2
    Const LastSlide = 21
    Set oDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Randomize
    For i = FirstSlide To LastSlide
        RSN = Int((LastSlide - FirstSlide + 1) * Rnd + FirstSlide)
        Set Sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(RSN)
        ' Get the first line
        aTxt = Split(Sld.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text, Chr(13))
        ' Check if the first line is duplicated
        If Not oDic.exists(aTxt(0)) Then
            ' Move slide
            Sld.MoveTo FirstSlide
            oDic(aTxt(0)) = ""
            If oDic.Count = NumStop Then Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Split function](https://learn.microsoft.comP/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: This seems to solve my dilemma.. thank you